# Two fullscreen windows on two different monitors

Tags: c, windows, winapi

For a project of mine I want to open two fullscreen windows on two different monitors. I use ChangeDisplaySettingsEx() to make each monitor switch to the resolution I need (currently, each monitor is switched to 640x480). Then I want to open a WS_POPUP window that covers the whole screen on each monitor. To make sure that the window stays up front, I also set the WS_EX_TOPMOST flag.

This is all working fine as long as only a single monitor is concerned. Once I try to open a second fullscreen window on the other monitor, my window on the first monitor of course loses its focus and suddenly appears behind other windows which looks really ugly because we're in 640x480 now. This behaviour is of course logical because there can be only one topmost window but how am I supposed to use two fullscreen windows on two different monitors then? I'd somehow need to force *both* windows to stay up front and cover all the other windows behind them.

Is there a clean way to implement such a thing or is this not possible at all without resorting to hacky not-so-sure-whether-it-will-work-in-newer-or-older-Windows-versions approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: Any number of windows can have the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` window style. A window also doesn't lose this window style when if loses input focus. Without seeing the code it's hard to tell where you went wrong.

Comment: What happens if your program fails and doesn't revert the display resolution? This would be unacceptable in any application. (Except maybe kiosks and the like.) Just saying.

Comment: It's actually for a kiosk system :)

Comment: @Andreas Carry on, then. :)

Comment: @IInspectable: Right, the MSDN docs seem to confirm this. I guess I'll have to investigate some more then... maybe it's really a problem in my code.

Comment: Ok, it was a bug in my code. Changing the resolution of the first monitor *after* changing the resolution of the second one of course invalidated window positions in the second monitor. I've just forgotten to move the window on the second monitor back into its correct place. Problem solved!

Comment: If this is a kiosk app then why on Earth are there any other processes with windows running?  You of course have to lock down the machine so this is never possible.

Comment: Well, there won't be any in end-user mode but of course there are other processes during development.

Answer (score 1):

> It's actually for a kiosk system :)

This should of course never be a *real* problem on a kiosk application.  You should *never* have any other processes running that create windows.  Locking down the machine so this cannot happen is essential.

That's not where it ends.  It doesn't make sense to force the video mode either.  That should of course have been done as well when the machine was configured.  Your ChangeDisplaySettingsEx() call isn't only unnecessary, it is *harmful*.  Since now changing the monitor(s) may well require a software update.  Keep in mind that this is not unlikely, the monitor is usually the part of the kiosk that wears the quickest.

Don't help too much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean way to implement this, especially on kiosk system. Have your desktop spanning over the two monitors and then have one window positioned so that it covers both monitors - full desktop, that is from top left corner of the left monitor to bottom right corner of the right  monitor (as opposed to regular maximization to single current monitor only). With a single foreground window you should have no focus issues any longer.